# Getting error ORA-12154 after installing ODP.net how to solve?

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, ado, odp.net

Am getting below error after installing ODP.net.

ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Before installing ODP.net i was able to connect with database using plsql developer.But ODP.net is required to run .net application so i installed ODP.net.But after installing ODP.net am unable to connect with database using plsql develper and .net code. Error am getting is "
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified "

Let me know if anyone knows the solution for this.

Comment: check the `TNS listener` runs.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed the latest ODP.net the Oracle Installer may have created a new Oracle_Home.  You need to find the sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora files from your original home and copy them to the new Oracle Home.

For example.  If your first ODP.net installation was to:

C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1

and if your second ODP.net installation was to

C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_2

then you need to copy the files from

C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_1\Network\Admin

to

C:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\client_2\Network\Admin